# CLONE_SIGHAND flag makes clone() fail

Tags: c, linux, clone

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1024*64

int foo(void* args){
    // int arg = (int)args;
    printf("this is thread\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}

void main(){
    pid_t pid;
    void* stack;
    stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    if(stack == 0) {
        perror("malloc: cound not allocate stack\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("start\n");

    if ( (pid = clone(foo, (char*)stack+STACK_SIZE,  SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_VM | CLONE_SIGHAND , NULL)) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error with %d\n", errno);
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    printf("end aa\n");
}
```

This is my test code for testing `clone()` with `SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_VM | CLONE_SIGHAND` flags, which is needed for my university assignment which uses `clone()` for user-mode threading.

Anyways, that `CLONE_SIGHAND` flag makes the pid -1. If I delete it then `foo()` works perfectly.

Why does `CLONE_SIGHAND` break it?

+++ added ++
with SIGHAND flag : 
[image]

without SIGHAND flag :

[image]

Comment: What is `errno` set to when it fails?

Comment: It works fine on my system. No error from `clone()` and I see the `this is thread` printout.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks ive checked errno and errno is 22. which is EINVAL Invalid argument... does my workspace have problem? every other comments says that my code just works fine..

Comment: ive checked clone() man page https://linux.die.net/man/2/clone here, but EINVAL errno related to CLONE_SIGHAND is  just these two : EINVAL

CLONE_SIGHAND was specified, but CLONE_VM was not. (Since Linux 2.6.0-test6.)

EINVAL

CLONE_THREAD was specified, but CLONE_SIGHAND was not. (Since Linux 2.5.35.)

Comment: ---- this doesnt work just on wsl. Works fine on Ubuntu on Vmware